# Output data from two tables using most recent entry

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, union

I have done a good search for a similar question, but with no joy.  I think the answer to my question is based around DISTINCT, GROUP and UNION, but just can't put the together in any way which makes sense.

I have 2 tables:

```
users(id, username)
activitylog(id, userid, usernamedisp, activity)
```

Sample data:

```
users 
id, username
 1, Joe Bloggs
 2, Jane Doe
 3, John Smith

activitylog
id, userid, usernamedisp, activity
 1,      3, John Smith  , logged in
 2,      3, John Smith  , visited about us page
 3,      1, Joe Bloggs  , logged in
 4,      3, John Smith  , logged out
 5,      2, Jane Doe    , logged in
 6,      1, Joe Bloggs  , logged out
 7,      2, Jane Doe    , visited about us page
```

(there is another unrelated but valid reason why the user's name appears in both tables)

I want the output to list the users in order of users.id along with activitylog.username and finally only the most recent activitylog.activity, which should look as follows:

```
User, Username  , Last Activity 
   1, Joe Bloggs, logged out 
   2, Jane Doe  , visited about us page
   3, John Smith, logged out
```

While I could do this by running a query inside a loop on each result (SELECT activity from activitylog where userid = $foo ORDER BY id DESC, LIMIT 0,1) - I would rather run it all off in one nice clean piece of code as the number of users could be between 50-100 and that's too many queries for my comfort.

I'm sure this is possible, but I just can't seem to put it together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu need a two-part query: one to get the list of usersIDs and their "max" id, which would be their latest activity. Then a container query which takes those IDs and fetches the rest of the information:

```
SELECT activitylog.userid, users.username, activitylog.activity
FROM activitylog
LEFT JOIN users ON activitylog.userid = users.id
WHERE activitylog.id IN (
   SELECT MAX(id)
   FROM activitylog
   GROUP BY userid
)
```

Comment: thanks for your speedy reply, however the code you have listed above returns just a single result... the user to with the highest/most recent activitylog.id

Comment: it shouldn't. the subquery would return the last id for every user in the activity table.

Comment: @MarcB the ActivityLog doesnot have a username column, you probably should replace the group by column to userid/usernamedisp. Probably that's what is causing the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: AH yes, true enough. should be `userid`. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @SoulTrain, your tweak got Marc B's code working perfectly.  To go a step further, if there was a fourth user with the users.id '4' but that user didn't yet have any appearance in the activitylog table, is it possible for them to be returned in the query too (obviously with some blank fields)?

Comment: Change your query to a `RIGHT JOIN`. But you have to re-position your `WHERE` clause, the clause as it is wont work since it will limit your result set based on the data in `activitylog` table, which you dont want in this case.

Comment: @SoulTrain - beginning to feel quite stupid now, but not quite sure where the "WHERE" clause needs to be moved.  Any chance you could throw the code up as a new answer?

Answer (score 0):

Contd. from discussion in comments...

This query should get you the next solution set you are looking for.

```
SELECT AL.userid
    ,users.username
    ,AL.activity
FROM users
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT activitylog.userid
        ,activitylog.activity
    FROM activitylog
    WHERE activitylog.id IN (
            SELECT MAX(id)
            FROM activitylog
            GROUP BY userid
            )
    ) as AL ON AL.userid = users.id
```